# ADF Mobile Login Validation Error

Tags: oracle, mobile, jdeveloper, oracle-adf-mobile

This is George.

I am getting one error while working with ADF Mobile login app.
I have developed as described in this link : (please visit the link)
http://andrejusb.blogspot.in/2012/10/adf-mobile-login-functionality.html

I have done same that is mentioned there but I am unable to get login success in my Android simulator. I am getting the error as "Login Error. Can not connect to login server. Check the Network and try again."

I cant find any solution over in that link page.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your login server is accessible from your mobile device - try to access the URL you provided in ADF Mobile through the browser on your mobile device to check accessibility.